# Centos 7 nmcli creating new connections after reload

Tags: centos7, networkmanager

I have a Centos 7 server, on which I have configured two connections for the two NICs the server has. When I issue the command `nmcli con show`, I get this:

```
[root@aplicaciones ~ ]# nmcli con show
NOMBRE            UUID                                  TIPO            DISPOSITIVO 
interfaz-interna  a0dee7c2-b230-45fd-a94f-5d4c5142b1ce  802-3-ethernet  enp2s0      
conexión-claro    67ca0559-3717-4fdb-b1e7-49ab9bf4225a  802-3-ethernet  enp4s0
```

However when I execute `systemctl restart NetworkManager`, I get two connections more, which become the current active connections:

```
[root@aplicaciones ~ ]# nmcli con show
NOMBRE            UUID                                  TIPO            DISPOSITIVO 
enp2s0            368b4bbd-de95-4fa3-b1b8-80a834cb8374  802-3-ethernet  enp2s0      
interfaz-interna  a0dee7c2-b230-45fd-a94f-5d4c5142b1ce  802-3-ethernet  --          
conexión-claro    67ca0559-3717-4fdb-b1e7-49ab9bf4225a  802-3-ethernet  --          
enp4s0            70964741-665f-4aa0-956a-98718cbaa67f  802-3-ethernet  enp4s0
```

Why is happening this?

For the record, when I first installed Centos, I had a connection called enp2s0, which I edited to change its name (id) to "interfaz-interna". The same goes to the connection for enp4s0, which I renamed to "conexión-claro" in order to document which connection is external and which is internal.

When I delete the new connections with `nmcli con delete 368b4bbd-de95-4fa3-b1b8-80a834cb8374` and `nmcli con delete 70964741-665f-4aa0-956a-98718cbaa67f` the connections "interfaz-interna" and "conexión-claro" become active again, but as soon as I restart NetworkManager the connections are recreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was a bug on NetworkManager. I updated to CentOS 7.1 and now it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to remove the files from:

```
[vagrant@controller ~]$ ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
ifcfg-enp0s3  ifdown-post      ifup-bnep   ifup-routes
ifcfg-enp0s8  ifdown-ppp       ifup-eth    ifup-sit
ifcfg-lo      ifdown-routes    ifup-ippp   ifup-Team
ifdown        ifdown-sit       ifup-ipv6   ifup-TeamPort
ifdown-bnep   ifdown-Team      ifup-isdn   ifup-tunnel
ifdown-eth    ifdown-TeamPort  ifup-plip   ifup-wireless
ifdown-ippp   ifdown-tunnel    ifup-plusb  init.ipv6-global
ifdown-ipv6   ifup             ifup-post   network-functions
ifdown-isdn   ifup-aliases     ifup-ppp    network-functions-ipv6
```